# Pass Radio Button Value Onchange

Tags: yii

In Yii, the list view used as a search result.
Controller

```
 public function actionSearch()
        {
           $key=$_GET['Text'];
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->addSearchCondition('username',$key,true,"OR");
            $criteria->select = "`username`,`country`"; 
           $data=new CActiveDataProvider('User',
                   array('criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>5),
            ));
           $this->render('search', array(
           'ModelInstance' => User::model()->findAll($criteria),
           'dataProvider'=>$data,
            ));               

        }
```

search.php

```
<?php
//THE WIDGET WITH ID AND DYNAMICALLY MADE SORTABLEATTRIBUTES PROPERTY

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'id'=>'user-list',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'results',
        'template' => '{sorter}{items}{pager}',
));
?>
<?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList('type','',array(
                    '1'=>'Personal',
                    '2'=>'Organization'),array('id'=>'type'),array( 'separator' => "<br/>",'style'=>'display:inline')
                );
                ?>
```

result.php

```
<?php echo $data->username."<br>"; ?>
<?php echo $data->country; ?>
```

The user model fields are id, name , country, type, The search result shows the name and country. Now want to filter the results based on the radio button onchange (personal/organisation).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [$.fn.yiiListView.update](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js) method passing list view's id (`user-list` in your case) and [ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as arguments. `data` property of ajax settings is what can be used to specify GET-parameters that will be passed to your `actionSearch` to update the list view. So you have to analyze these parameters in the action and alter `CDbCriteria` instance depending on them.

The following script to bind onchange handler to your radio button list is to be registered in the view:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("init-search-radio-button-list", "
    $('input[name=\"type\"]').change(function(event) {
        var data = {
            // your GET-parameters here
        }
        $.fn.yiiListView.update('user-list', {
            'data': data
            // another ajax settings if desired
        })
    });
", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

You also may consider [the following code](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/229/filter-search-with-clistview/) as an example based on [common technique of filtering CGridView results](http://queirozf.com/reminders/yii-cgridview-filter-examples).

By the way, for performance reasons you can render your view partially in the case of ajax update:

```
$view = 'search';
$params = array(
    'ModelInstance' => User::model()->findAll($criteria),
    'dataProvider' => $data
);
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    $this->renderPartial($view, $params);
else
    $this->render($view, $params);
```